# How to install autoconf

Tags: installation, apt

I need to install Tesseract, that need to install autoconf automake libtool,
However I got the error as follows:

```
sahu@sahu-desktop:/$ sudo apt-get install autoconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package autoconf is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'autoconf' has no installation candidate
```

So please help me.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 57):

Make sure you have enabled all necessary repositories. Do a '[How do I enable repository](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how%20do%20i%20enable%20repository)' search on the site. After enabling the repositories, open a terminal and use these commands to install autoconf

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

Your error messege suggested that, you have disabled repository.

Answer (score 2):

> Autoconf is a GPLv2-licensed package of macros that produces a shell
>   script "configure" to generate a Makefile and config header for a
>   project. The configuration scripts produced by Autoconf are
>   self-contained, so the users of your project do not need Autoconf, M4,
>   or perl to run configure.<sup>1</sup>

To download the latest version click [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/), and for instructions on how to install, click [here](http://petio.org/tools/autoconf.html).

You need to Extract Autoconf, Build it, and Install Autoconf (must be root user)

Another way is to install from the Ubuntu Software Center,

Also To download and install click the image below.

[image: Install via the software center]

You can also follow Anwar's answer.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Autoconf](http://petio.org/tools/autoconf.html)</sup>

Comment: Isn't autoconf in the repositories...?

Comment: This is the wrong approach unless you really need a specific (new) version

Comment: @Chris Care to share the right approach?

Comment: Clearly the OP had a problem with apt setup. The correct thing to do is fix that, not just starting installing packages by hand (unless there is a very specific reason to need a version not available from your installation).

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. `autoconf --version` shows `autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69`, but I need at least 2.71. Here's how:

### How to build the latest version of `autoconf` from source

Find the latest here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/ --> "Downloading Autoconf" section, which
leads to here: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/. Use the link of the latest version at the link just above in the cmds below:

```bash
# check version
autoconf --version
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.71.tar.xz
tar -xf autoconf-2.71.tar.xz
cd autoconf-2.71/
./configure
time make 
sudo make install 
. ~/.profile
autoconf --version  # you should see your new version now!
```